# How to improve this query to avoid hash match

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan

I have q query to select ID of duplicated rows. If the provinceID is same and at least one phonenumber is same, then we can determine that two rows are identicial.

```
SELECT i1.ID 
            FROM pigeon.dbo.Instrument i1
            WHERE EXISTS(
                SELECT i2.ID 
                FROM pigeon.dbo.Instrument i2
                WHERE i2.ID != i1.ID and i2.ProvinceID = i1.ProvinceID and
                (
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3))) or
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3))) or 
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3)))
                )           
            )
```

The query excution plan

[image]

Whilst the other similar query performs very well, and no hash match in execution plan. The query is

```
SELECT i1.ID 
            FROM pigeon.dbo.Instrument i1
            WHERE EXISTS(
                SELECT i2.ID 
                FROM pigeon.dbo.Instrument i2
                WHERE i2.ID != i1.ID and i2.Name = i1.Name and 
                (
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber1) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3))) or
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber2) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3))) or 
                    (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) != '' and (RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber1) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber2) or RTRIM(i2.PhoneNumber3) = RTRIM(i1.PhoneNumber3)))
                )
            )
```

The execution plan is

[image]

I created index for all fields which is included in where clause.

[image]

The table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instrument](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
[Gender] [char](1) NULL,
[Birthdate] [datetime] NULL,
[PhoneNumber1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PhoneNumber2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PhoneNumber3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[IDType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[IDNumber] [nchar](32) NULL,
[ProvinceID] [char](16) NOT NULL,
[CityID] [char](16) NOT NULL,
[Blacklist] [bit] NULL,
[BeenProject] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[BeenCity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[BeenDate] [datetime] NULL,
[BeenRemark] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[PlateType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[PlateNumber] [nchar](16) NULL,
[Color] [nchar](16) NULL,
[Vendor] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[ModelID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Version] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[Level] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[ModelEx] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[Van] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[Volume] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[EngineNumber] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[VINNumber] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[ShipmentDate] [datetime] NULL,
[BoughtDate] [datetime] NULL,
[RegisteDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Remark1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Remark2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Remark3] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Remark4] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Remark5] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Referer] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[Shared] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Counter] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[XRefID] [bigint] NULL,
[Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nchar](32) NOT NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedBy] [nchar](32) NULL,
[UpdatedAt] [datetime] NULL
```

)

Why their's execution plan is so different? The second query's performance is very good compare to the first query. Please help to improve the performance of the first query.

Comment: how many distinct `proviceid` in table and how many distinct `name` in table?

Comment: Why not just select all and group by province, phone number, having count greater than one. Then throw that into a temporary table or a subquery and delete the duplicate ids.

Comment: provinceid is less 30, name is more than 30000

Comment: @joshstrike, thanks, I will try your approach later.